# Using var in a nested function to declare a variable with the same name as a parameter of parent

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript to write some code and found an unexpected behaviour.

I'm using a nested function `g` inside `f`. `f` has a parameter named `m`. When using and declaring a variable inside `g` with the same name, something weird happens:

```
var f = function(m) {
    var g = function() {
        alert(m);
        var m = 0;
    };
    g();
};
f(1);
```

This code will result in `undefined`, instead of `1` which I expected.

Moving the `alert` statement below the `var` line would result in the answer `0` which makes sense.

I suppose this is because JavaScript are only using functions as name closures, `var m` will be attached to function `g` with the declaration, but `m` is not assigned yet at the time of `alert`.

But I am not sure about this, because if the function is not nested, there behaviour looks nice to me:

```
var g = function(m) {
    alert(m);
    var m = 0;
};
g(1);
```

would produce `1`.

Could anyone explain? Thank you.

Comment: Is there any other code that code be affectig it?  The behaviour here is not as you describe: http://jsfiddle.net/QvcqU/

Comment: @shanethehat: sorry, I meant `undefined`.

Comment: When i run your first block of code i get undefined.

Comment: @herostwist: yes, it's `undefined`. I have edited the question.

Comment: The reason the second one produces 1 is because you have m as a formal parameter, then pass 1 to the function so it is assigned a value when the function is called. Later, m is set to 0 when the assignment m=0 is processed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript uses function-scope, meaning that variables' scope is not like C's block-scope coming into and out of scope according to `{}`, but rather objects come into and out of scope by functions' beginnings and endings. As such, every local variable you define in a function is declared from the beginning of the execution of that function, and will be of type `undefined` until you initialise it in your function.

As such, when `g` executes, since it will create at some point the local variable `m`, the runtime already declares that there is a local `m` (which obviously hides the external m of the `f` function) with type `undefined` *from the beginning of `g`'s execution*

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet which explains that when you do `var varName` it hoists the variable to the top of the function scope. That page has lots of great examples, here's one quote that sums it up:

> Every definition of a variable is really a **declaration** of the variable at the *top of its scope* and an **assignment** at the *place where the definition is*.

Comment: Although this explanation is sound, I don't think it answers the question, namely why parameters are treated differently from definitions in outside scope. I guess the answer very well might be: that's just how it is.